# Calculate the percentage of the total for each row

Tags: powerbi, dax

My main table `costs`, is like this:

```
Acc       Item         Group     Origin      Money
acc1      Item1        Adm       Soc          14,3
acc2      Item1        Adm       Soc          1,0
acc3      Item2        Pers      Bnk          4,5
acc4      Item2        Pers      Bnk         -45,2
acc5      Item3        Amort     Adj         -745,7
acc6      Item4        Adm       Adj          67,8
acc7      Item4        Amort     Bnk          87,0
acc8      Item4        Adm       Soc         -200,0
acc9      Item5        Adm       Bnk         -34,0
acc10     Item6        Pers      Bnk         -23,0
acc11     Item4        Adm       Adj          -7,8
acc12     Item4        Adm       Adj          -745,0
acc13     Item4        Adm       Adj          -82,0
acc14     Item4        Adm       Adj          -14,0
acc15     Item4        Adm       Adj          -2,0
```

I have no other tables made and related to the main one. I'm calculating things in DAX with filters. I made This measure: Var_neg_adm_adj (Var_neg = Negative variations) to brings the negative money values with this filters in the columns:

`Group`= `Adm`

`Origin`=`Adj`

`Money < 0`.

```
Var_neg_adm_adj= CALCULATE(SUM(Costs[Money]),
FILTER(Costs, Cost[Group]="Adm"),
FILTER(Costs), Cost[Origin]="Adj"
FILTER(Costs), Cost[Money] < 0)
)
```

So i got this:

```
Acc       Item         group     Origin      Money
acc11     Item4        Adm       Adj         -7,8
acc12     Item4        Adm       Adj         -745,0
acc13     Item4        Adm       Adj         -82,0
acc14     Item4        Adm       Adj         -14,0
acc15     Item4        Adm       Adj         -2,0
Total                                        -850,8
```

What I want: A column in DAX with the percentages/weights that each row contributes to the summed total.

```
Acc       Item         group     Origin      Money    Percentage
acc11     Item4        Adm       Adj         -7,8       0,9%
acc12     Item4        Adm       Adj         -745,0     87,5%
acc13     Item4        Adm       Adj         -82,0      9,4%
acc14     Item4        Adm       Adj         -14,0      1,64%
acc15     Item4        Adm       Adj         -2,0       0,2%
Total                                        -850,8     100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ALLSELECTED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax) to get the total.

```
Percentage =
  DIVIDE(
    [Var_neg_adm_adj],
    CALCULATE([Var_neg_adm_adj], ALLSELECTED('Costs'))
  )
```